# Associar duas tabelas com python

Tags: python-3.x

Olá! Eu tenho duas tabelas com x e y e preciso associar essas colunas. Acontece que o x e y da tabela 1 não são exatamente iguais o x e y da tabela 2. São valores próximos, mas não iguais, então eu precisava de uma função que conseguisse "ver" o x de uma tabela e procurar pelo x mais próximo da outra tabela. É possível fazer isso?

Obrigada.